# Where is the right place to install Codeigniter 4 (in the root folder "html" or its sub-directories)?

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I want to start learning CI. I have LAMP with Ubuntu 16.04 on Virtual Box 7.0
I don't understand this. I have noticed that everyone sets CI to its own folder below root. Lise so:
www/html/codeigniter
And unpack its files here and as a result we have something like
localhost/codeigniter
What's the point doing that? After all, we usually put our files in the root folder "html". OR the site should not be installed in the same folder alongside CI? Thus the site goes to the html folder, and CI goes to another one so they don't interfere with each other?
Suppose in the future I will have some kind of CRM on CI. I want to put it on localhost.
Then where should the CI files be? TOGETHER with the CRM script files OR in its own separate sub-directory?

I'm not yet trying or expecting anything. I'm just asking my question.

Answer (score -1):

Codeigniter is MVC framework which follows some folder and file pattern. You can create your CRM application. Here is sample folder structure you would like to have to achieve this.

Extract Codeigniter in place where you want place your application

Copy everything except `system` folder in new folder `crm`

```
// your root directory will look like

-- system
-- crm
```

Now in `crm` folder change `app/config/Path.php` to new system path.

If you want to run you application from `crm` instead of `crm/public` copy all files from `crm/public` to `crm` folder make change to `index.php` in `crm` folder to point app directory.

```
// your crm directory will look like

-- app
-- public
-- test
-- writeable
-- index.php
-- favicon.ico
-- .htaccess

etc.
```

You can also directly rename app to crm if you don't want to follow above steps. But it is not recommended if you don't know what you are doing. As you will require to follow `crm` instead of `app` `namespace` throughout your application

Comment: I didn't understand a thing.

Comment: @DavidW: [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) wouldn't misspell [CodeIgniter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeIgniter). E.g., when prompted with the title of the question, it uses "CodeIgniter" in the output. [Articles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) are also ***completely*** missing.

Comment: @PeterMortensen You're right I think. They posted three answers that I'm pretty convinced are ChatGPT around the same time, but this one probably isn't. I should have looked more carefully